# selector not picking drawable value with ques mark, like "?ic_submit"

Tags: android

I'm using customized themes in my application.

In **themes.xml**, I've mentioned:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="ic_submit_button">@drawable/ic_submit_mytheme</item>
    <item name="ic_submit_button_pressed">@drawable/ic_submit_mytheme_pressed</item>
</style>
```

**attrs.xml**

```
<resources>
    <attr name="ic_submit_button" format="integer" /> 
    <attr name="ic_submit_button_pressed" format="integer" /> 
</resources>
```

**layout.xml**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ic_submit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_submit_selector" />
```

**ic_submit_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="?ic_submit_button" android:state_pressed="false"></item>
    <item android:drawable="?ic_submit_button_pressed"></item>
</selector>
```

**Issue:**
I want to show the states of button pressed/unpressed, but **selector.xml** is not picking value with **"?"**.

**Error:**

```
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:181)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2092)
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your attributes in `attrs.xml` be defined as **reference**?

```
<resources>
    <attr name="ic_submit_button" format="reference" /> 
    <attr name="ic_submit_button_pressed" format="reference" /> 
</resources>
```

Answer (score -1):

The xml layout file could not be parsed. Stick to the allowed naming methods [a-z][0-9]... no special characters and no number at the beginning of the file.